# Surface Integral Q

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I've been revising this area and I've completely forgotten what I'm doing and my notes are sketchy.

Evaluate $\int r \cdot  dS$ over the surface of the sphere, radius a, centred at the origin.

Would you take $r = a\sin\theta \cos\phi + a\sin\theta \sin\phi + a\cos\theta $ and $dS = |\frac {dr}{d\theta} \times \frac {dr}{d\phi}|d\theta d\phi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sphere is the set of all points $(x, y, z)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2$. Where $r>0$ is constant with respect to $x, y, x$.Informally, this means that $r(x,y,z) =r$ for r fixed. Then,

$$
\int r\, dS = r\cdot \int 1\, dS
$$

Areas of surfaces are given for double integrals. And double integrals has two variables. Therefore we need a parameterization of the sphere with only two variables. See spherical coodinates [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html).
\begin{align}
x(\theta,\varphi)= &r\cdot\cos\theta\sin\varphi \\
y(\theta,\varphi)= &r\cdot\sin \theta \sin\varphi\\
z(\theta,\varphi)= &r\cdot\cos\varphi
\end{align}
and define the vectorial function 
$$
\vec{\Phi}(\theta,\varphi)=\bigg(x(\theta,\varphi),y(\theta,\varphi),z(\theta,\varphi)\bigg)
$$
\begin{align}
\int r\, dS = r\cdot \int 1\, dS = 
&
r\cdot\int_{\begin{array}{c}0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi \\ 0\leq \varphi \leq \pi \end{array} }
\left\|\vec{\Phi}_\varphi\times\vec{\Phi}_\theta \right\| d A
\\
=
&
r\cdot \int_{0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi }\int_{0\leq \varphi \leq \pi} \left\|\vec{\Phi}_\varphi\times\vec{\Phi}_\theta \right\| d\varphi \, d\theta.
\\
\end{align}
Here $\left\|\Phi_\varphi\times\Phi_\theta \right\|$ is the modulus of [cross produtc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) $\Phi_\varphi\times\Phi_\theta $.

Comment: Thanks! I thought my arithmetic was out, but I got dS as $a^2sin\phi d\theta d\phi$ eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the divergence theorem, which says that the integral of a normal component of vector function over a closed surface is equal to the integral of the divergence of that function through the volume enclosed by that surface.  As $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{r}=3$, the integral is simply $4 \pi r^3$.